# creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i generate a springboot  project from spring.io and i add a web service and jpa from spring.io , i use intellij 13 , and my database is db2,but when run a application i have this error
please helpe me:

spring initializr:

[image]

The detailed error is given below

```
2019-12-01 10:59:47.784  INFO 4308 --- [           main] c.e.connectdb.ConnectdbApplication       : Starting ConnectdbApplication on hosseini-PC with PID 4308 (D:\springboot-samples\connectdb2\connectdb\connectdb\target\classes started by hosseini in D:\springboot-samples\connectdb2\connectdb\connectdb)
2019-12-01 10:59:47.787  INFO 4308 --- [           main] c.e.connectdb.ConnectdbApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-01 10:59:48.645  INFO 4308 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-01 10:59:48.718  INFO 4308 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-12-01 10:59:49.176  INFO 4308 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d6e2ad5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-01 10:59:49.610  INFO 4308 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-01 10:59:49.654  INFO 4308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-01 10:59:49.655  INFO 4308 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-12-01 10:59:49.813  INFO 4308 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-01 10:59:49.814  INFO 4308 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1965 ms
2019-12-01 10:59:50.001  INFO 4308 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-12-01 10:59:50.155  WARN 4308 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
2019-12-01 10:59:50.159  INFO 4308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-01 10:59:50.169  INFO 4308 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-01 10:59:50.175 ERROR 4308 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.example.connectdb.ConnectdbApplication.main(ConnectdbApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
    at hit.db2sql.k.<init>(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.j.b(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.j.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.z.c(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.z.d(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.y.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.y.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.c.<init>(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2.Db2Driver.newConnection(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at hit.db2sql.b.connect(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:357) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c44ed44.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c44ed44$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$38afa4bb.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c44ed44.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

application.property :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://0.0.0.0:0000/sample
spring.datasource.username=xx
spring.datasource.password=xx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=hit.db2.Db2Driver
```

maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>connectdb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>connectdb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hit.db2.db2Driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>hitlicense</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hit.db2.db2Driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>hitjdbcdb2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "LEVEL")
    private String level;


    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "PERSONEL_ID")
    private String personelId;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "TEL")
    private String tel;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "CODE")

    private String code;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPersonelId() {
        return personelId;
    }

    public void setPersonelId(String personelId) {
        this.personelId = personelId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }  
}
```

repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users,Long>{

}
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/a")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Users> get()
    {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your file with configurations called `application.property` or `application.properties`? Because it has to be called `application.properties` if following the convention.

Comment: use application.property

Comment: The error is quite clear `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter`. The bug/issue is also documented by IBM [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC74895), either add a property or upgrade the driver.

Answer (score 0):

By default, spring-boot loads properties from application.properties in classpath using PropertiesFactoryBean.
If you using 'application.property' it will be unable to 'see' your database settings for JPA